# AS3 compress a string to send it in POST protocol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compression

I'm developing a flash binary that execute an animation in some web pages, and during this time I want to get the current source code of the page and send it via a POST call.

To get current source code I execute some javascript like this :

```
src = ExternalInterface.call("function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML;}");
```

At this point, no problem.

After that, as the source code could be very huge, I wanted to compress it, so I tried to work with BiteArray like this :

```
var dataSrc:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
dataSrc.writeUTFBytes(src); // xmlData is original XML string
dataSrc.compress();
```

At this point, how could I send this to some server script (here I use PHP) ?
I mean : I don't want to know how to send data to an URL (I will use `URL Loader`), but how should I set my variable ?

Directly `dataSrc` or `data.toString()` ?

Comment: I don't have a project in front of me to test with, but could you run Charles or Fiddler2 to monitor your network activity and see what the size of the request is compared to the length of the string? I want to say that AS3 automatically compresses string data, though I'm not 100% sure. If it does, converting to a ByteArray and manually compressing (which creates a ZIP file) is unnecessary.

Comment: In fact my problem was to transmit my data to my server script. I tested your answer and what I see is that my transmitted data had the same size, so 2 things could happen : AS3 don't automatically compress or, as my data was already compressed by ByteArray it's was transmitted as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compressing with ByteArray, I just `Base64Encode` my result, transmit it to my server script, and in this script I `Base64Decode` and `gzuncompress`.

Why should I `Base64Encode` ? Because to transmit the data to the server, my data is converted in a string and doing this cause bit lose, and padding errors ... `Base64Encode` permits to convert each bit of my data in a valid string to communicate.